# how to sort an NSArray with a nested NSArray

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nspredicate

Hi I'm new with the Objective-C and i try to do some try.
I have an NSArray called "values". It is an array of array. It seems like :

["0"  = > "aString",6872,5523,0091]

["1"  = > "anotherString",4422,1234,0091]

["2"  = > "aString",6812,2143,0314]          ...

How do I sort the "values" array than the first integer value? 
I should use the NSPredicate ? 
please help me with some example.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that with block (assuming that your integer value are NSNumber or some class that can be compared):

```
NSArray *sortArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id elt1, id elt2) {
    return [[elt1 objectAtIndex:1] compare:[elt2 objectAtIndex:1]];
    } ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had found another one using this method static NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [[num1 objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
    int v2 = [[num2 objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
and this declaration : [values sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL] where values are the NSArray with the object to sort.